# print option is not displayed in report viewer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, rdlc

I'm working on RDLC reports in ASP.NET, and rendering a report in a report viewer. It displays the print option at design time, but it disappears at runtime even if I set the property `ShowPrint` to `true`.

Comment: What windows form control are you using as your Report viewer?

Comment: I am using webform control in aspx page.

Comment: Not sure about webforms, but I am using a Crystal Report viewer control and that has it by default. Can you use that instead?

Answer (score 0):

The print button unfortunately relies on ActiveX, which is only available on Internet Explorer, and so the print button is not present when using other browsers. You can still generate a .pdf file and then print that, effectively getting the same result.